# Tkinter: Does anyone know how to change a button into a image?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code for the button that opens an app:

Modules:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from subprocess import Popen
```

Importing Image:

```
path = ("C:\Pictures\GoogleLogo.png")
img = Image.open(path)
img = img.resize((96, 96), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

Generic Canvas Button:

```
def openCalc():
    Popen("calc.exe")

openCalcWin = tk.Button(text='Calculator', command=openCalc, bg="Grey", height = 6, width = 10)
canvas.create_window(1167,714, window=openCalcWin)
```

What I have Tried:

I attempted to make the background of the button into an image by using `bg` or `img`. But this just creates an tiny image logo that can't be clicked. Indicating that there was an error loading the image, but there was no error code or anything in the IDLE Shell.

There was other attempts of code that I forgot, but most of them ends up the same: no button appeared and no error code.

**Edit:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from subprocess import Popen

##Application Window:
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Virtual Desktop")
root.resizable(False, False)

#Determine Window Resolution
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1280, height=780, bg="#263D42")
canvas.pack()

#Importing Calulator Image
path = ("C:\Pictures\CalcLogo.png")
img = Image.open(path)
img = img.resize((96, 96), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)


#Calculator Button
def openCalc():
    Popen("calc.exe")

openCalcWin = tk.Button(text='Calculator', command=openCalc, bg="Grey", height = 6, width = 10)
canvas.create_window(1167,714, window=openCalcWin)
```

Comment: Do you need something like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-add-image-on-a-tkinter-button/)?

Comment: add a keyword argument when creating the button instance: `image=img`, also don't import everything from a module (don't use `*` when importing), and why do you use canvas to place the button?

Comment: @TheLizzard Hello, I have tried that once but I was unable to resize the Button afterward. I also had difficulty in changing where to put the button precisely; such as (x,y)

Comment: @Matiiss Hello, I was trying to shorten my code for uploading on StackOverflow. The program was very long and so I only took snippets and changed some of the names etc.

Comment: There is definitely a conflict between `from tkinter import *` and `from PIL import Image` (there's a `tkinter.Image` too). Regardless, I think you will need to provide a [mre] we don't want to see your entire code, just something runnable that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @BartSimpson why do you even need to put the button in a precise location? can't you simply use `.pack()` or `.grid()` and not have the Canvas as master because it seems unnecessary, anyhow, did you add the `image` argument? (`... = tk.Button(..., image=img, ...)`)

Comment: @martineau Hello, I have updated my question with an new code that I have tested to work on my end. It allows me to create a generic canvas button that opens up the Window Calculator.

Comment: @Matiiss I'll try that now.

Comment: oh, and I forgot to mention that if you use `image` argument then `width` and `height` are in pixels, so 8 and 6 as width and height will create a pretty small button since it will be like 8 x 6 pixels so either remove those arguments or increase the integers, can you also explain why you need to use canvas and set the button to specific place in pixels? for the majority of cases that is not necessary and then you have to handle dynamic widget positioning manually

Comment: @Matiiss I'm creating a spreadsheet-like program. So I want to add a button in a side-bar to allow users to quickly open up programs that are already installed.

Comment: @BartSimpson ok, you can still (and I would suggest) use `.pack()` or `.grid()`, just use a `Frame` to group those widgets to the side, and you don't need to worry for dynamic placement, it will also be a bit more organized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me. The most important change was to specify an `image=` keyword argument, when creating the `Button`.

The other thing I noted was the:

```
path = ("C:\Pictures\CalcLogo.png")
```

you had. The parentheses are unnecessary (but don't hurt), however you need to add an `r` prefix to all strings containing back-slash characters like paths on Windows.

```
path = r"C:\Pictures\CalcLogo.png"
```

or just use forward-slashes (which work fine on Windows):

```
path = "C:/Pictures/CalcLogo.png"
```

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from subprocess import Popen

##Application Window:
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Virtual Desktop")
root.resizable(False, False)

#Determine Window Resolution
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1280, height=780, bg="#263D42")
canvas.pack()

#Importing Calulator Image
path = "8-ball.png"  # My own image.
img = Image.open(path)
img = img.resize((96, 96), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)


#Calculator Button
def openCalc():
    Popen("calc.exe")

openCalcWin = tk.Button(text='Calculator', command=openCalc, bg="Grey",
                        image=img)
canvas.create_window(1167,714, window=openCalcWin)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It worked thank you so much. I previously had tried that too but the reason it didn't work was because I used bg=img or img=path instead of image=img.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution. You can check it learn about it yourself, but basically you do not provide any args when creating the obj/Button, you only provide the root, image and command, and it should work.

Something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from subprocess import Popen    

root = Tk()

path = ("C:\Pictures\GoogleLogo.png")
img = Image.open(path)
img = img.resize((96, 96), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

def openCalc():
    Popen("calc.exe")

openCalcWin = tk.Button(text='Calculator', image=img, command=openCalc)

openCalcWin.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

if you want, you can look at some examples and learn more here - https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-add-images-in-tkinter/

Comment: you can provide other arguments to the Button too tho, also don't import everything from a module (do not use `*` when importing)

Comment: @MarcusDev Thank you, the code worked on my end. I'll be taking a look at the link provided to see if I could implement it into my program by adjusting its position

Comment: @Matiiss Thank you, I have edit my code to not import everything in the module.